# Semantic UI Checkbox Modal Interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

#### Summary

Note: I will be referring to components by using [Component Name]

The [Checkbox] does not update properly when
used inside a modal.

#### Reproduction

I have written an example of the issue on CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxtesting-gu7pj?file=/src/checkboxDemo/checkboxModal/index.js

#### Expected Result

The [Checkbox] inside of the [Modal] will update when clicked.

#### Actual Result

The [Checkbox] outside of the [Modal] gets updated when toggling the [Checkbox] inside the [Modal]

Note how the [Checkbox] and the [Input] work fine on the main page but when a [Modal] is opened the [Checkbox] in the [Modal] does not toggle. The [Input] still works regardless of where it is.

#### Semantic UI Version

^0.88.2

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the same `id` prop for both instances of the `Form.Checkbox`. This is whats causing the Checkbox inside of the Modal to point to the Checkbox outside the Modal. You can either pass down a unique `id` for the checkbox through props to `CheckBoxModal` and then to `Form.Checkbox`, or remove the `id` prop and have the library handle assigning ids

```js
        <Form.Checkbox
          id="checkbox-bad-behavior-test" // same id for both checkboxes
          width={3}
          label="Bad CheckBox"
          style={{ marginTop: 33 }}
          checked={checkboxEnabled ?? false}
          onChange={(event, data) => {
            console.log(someModalObject);
            setCheckBoxEnabled(data.checked);
          }}
        />
```

Solution 1:

```js
       <Form.Checkbox
          id={checkboxID} // unique id passed down through props
          width={3}
          label="Bad CheckBox"
          style={{ marginTop: 33 }}
          checked={checkboxEnabled ?? false}
          onChange={(event, data) => {
            console.log(someModalObject);
            setCheckBoxEnabled(data.checked);
          }}
        />
```

Solution 2:

```js
       <Form.Checkbox
            // 'id' removed
          width={3}
          label="Bad CheckBox"
          style={{ marginTop: 33 }}
          checked={checkboxEnabled ?? false}
          onChange={(event, data) => {
            console.log(someModalObject);
            setCheckBoxEnabled(data.checked);
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense. I tested it and it seems to work. Do you happen to know why this behavior not mirrored for the [Input] since the ID's are still the same for that component?